# Shopify: how to get value of forloop.index outside of the loop?

Tags: for-loop, scope, shopify, liquid

When I attempt to assign the forloop index (or anything else) to a variable in a for-loop and then use it outside (after) the loop, the assigned value is lost. The code below is one of about 20 different approaches I have tried. None of them have worked. I just need to know if x contains y (so the variable can either be boolean or an integer or anything).

```
{% assign has_y = 0 %}
{% for x in collection %} 
  {% if x contains y %}
    <span style="display: none">{{ has_y | plus: 1 }}</span>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if has_y < 1 %}
   THIS DOESN'T WORK AS EXPECTED
{% endif %}
```

I'm confused about Shopify's scoping rules...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are outputting `{{ has_y | plus: 1 }}`, but not assigning anything to `has_y` inside the for loop.

Try this:

```
{% assign has_y = 0 %}

{% for x in collections %} 
  {% if x contains y %}
    {% assign has_y = has_y | plus: 1 %}
    <span style="display: none">{{ has_y }}</span>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if has_y < 1 %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

Or, if you want to use boolean values instead:

```
{% assign has_y = false %}

{% for x in collections %} 
  {% if x contains y %}
    {% assign has_y = true %}
    <span style="display: none">{{ has_y }}</span>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if has_y == false %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

Also, you may want to check your for loop `{% for x in collection %}`. `collection` is an object. Maybe you meant to iterate over `collection.products` or `collections` instead?

Comment: Thank you. I see I did not understand how the assignment or math filter worked. (I do know about iterating collections. I just simplified that part to reduce clutter in the pasted code.) Thanks again!

Comment: @MountainX No problems :)